# Add version control to azure deploy project?

Tags: eclipse, git, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a project in Eclipse to deploy our WorkerRoles and now I want to share the project with the rest of the development team with some source version control (like git).

The project actually have a folder called lib that have some .jar from the start (they are added by Eclipse Azure plugin). That I think is better to ignore in git but then how other people will get it? Is there a better aproach to this?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question a bit better. 

You want to include the .jar, but are not sure if you should or not?

Comment: More or less, normally when I have a project with maven (or other dependency manager) I don't add libraries to VC because you can get them with a command. And I think this is a good style. But now this libraries aren't managed with maven so if someone clone the project he hasn't the libraries. So the question is I must add them or there are another approach?